# text from [String] to a label.text isn't working the first time

Tags: swift

Working on a school project in swift (self learning this language) i need to make an **Get method HTTP request** with some Headerfields and throw it into json objects (this part working well).

After that i want to show the 5 last part of JsonObjects  from the newer to the older, so i decided to put them into a table of Strings and be able to assign those Strings (in order i wanted) to few UILabel.text.

When i push the button (assigned to the @IBAction) the first time the label don't change but the table is full (tried with print(self.tableau) before the   *}catch{* )

Variable initialisation :

```
var tableau: [String] = []

struct Donnee: Decodable                            
    {
      let device_id: String
      let raw: String
      let receivedString: String
      let time: String


        init(json : [String: Any]){
            device_id       = json["device_id"] as? String ?? ""
            raw             = json["raw"] as? String ?? ""
            receivedString  = json["receivedString"] as? String ?? ""
            time            = json["time"] as? String ?? ""

        }
    }
```

Code making problem:

```
@IBAction func sendButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Send HTTP GET Request

              // Define server side script URL
              let scriptUrl = "https://lora-thomas-slave.data.thethingsnetwork.org/api/v2/query?last=7d"

              // Create NSURL Ibject
              let myUrl = NSURL(string: scriptUrl);

              // Creaste URL Request
               let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);

              // Set request HTTP method to GET. It could be POST as well
               request.httpMethod = "GET"

              // Or it could be a single Authorization Token value
               request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
               request.addValue("key ttn-account-v2.*************", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

              // Excute HTTP Request
               URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {(data, response, error) in
                   do{
                       // Try to assign Json Lora data into an array of Structured data
                       let donne = try JSONDecoder().decode([Donnee].self, from: data!)

                       // For each data, print the received string
                       let compt: Int = donne.count         //compt = number of json objects
                       var j : Int = 0
                       var chaine: String = " "
                       var x : Int = 0
                       for i in donne{
                           if (j > (compt-6)){
                               chaine = i.time.split(separator: "T")[0]  + " " + i.time.split(separator: "T")[1].split(separator: ".")[0] + " : " + i.receivedString
                               self.tableau.append(chaine)
                               x += 1
                           }
                           j += 1
                       }
                   }catch{
                       print("error !")
                   }
               }.resume()


                    //This code is executing the second time that i pushed the button
                    //**********************//
                    if(self.tableau.count != 0){
                        self.labelMess0.text = self.tableau[4]
                        self.labelMess1.text = self.tableau[3]
                        self.labelMess2.text = self.tableau[2]
                        self.labelMess3.text = self.tableau[1]
                        self.labelMess4.text = self.tableau[0]
                    }
                  //**********************//
        }
```

i already tried to put the code between //********// before the catch but i got an error telling me that only the main thread can modify an UILabel.text ^^ (UILabel.text must be used from main thread only)

Someone know this kind of problems and maybe know the solution ? 
Thanks for help

**EDIT**

First thing done, the label change the first time but still don't update the label when i push the button again. (The purpose of that is to be able to make an history of strings via internet, so when a other information is assigned into the Table tableau[4] and the other changes, (the new Tableau[3] is the last Tableau[4]) the UIlabel.text doesn't seems to updates) The Table Tableau[] is well feeded :)

Comment: Surround your UI updates with `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}`,   `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.labelMess0.text = self.tableau[4]` and so on

Comment: Thanks!  yep don't have the knowledge for that thanks :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, thanks for the first question help, it work at the first push now, but do you have any answer or idea for the Edit part ?? :)

Comment: see my answer I just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comment you need to do the UI update on the main thread using

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    self.labelMess0.text = self.tableau[4]
    self.labelMess1.text = self.tableau[3]
    self.labelMess2.text = self.tableau[2]
    self.labelMess3.text = self.tableau[1]
    self.labelMess4.text = self.tableau[0]
}
```

Your second problem is that when you press the button again the new result is appended to the array meaning it will be at position 5 - 9 so you will need to clear your array first, `self.tableau.removeAll()`

Either do it directly in `sendButtonTapped` or maybe better you do it the first thing in the closure so your old values doesn't disappear if the request fails.

Comment: Right !! i didn't checked my array count haha, sorry! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`URLSession.shared.dataTask(` runs in  a background thread so any ui update should be embeded inside

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async { 

                if self.tableau.count >= 5 { // avoid crashes 
                    self.labelMess0.text = self.tableau[4]
                    self.labelMess1.text = self.tableau[3]
                    self.labelMess2.text = self.tableau[2]
                    self.labelMess3.text = self.tableau[1]
                    self.labelMess4.text = self.tableau[0]
                }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the first question help, it work at the first push now, but do you have any answer or idea for the Edit part ?? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with threads

```swift
@IBAction func sendButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    [...]
    // Object that holds http request information
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL)
    // set cookies, body, headers, whatever
    [...]

    [1]
    // now create download handler
    let downloadHandler = URLSession.shared.dataTask(
        with: request as URLRequest
    ) {
        [3]
        [some function to be executed when download finishes]
    }
    [2]
    // start download
    downloadHandler.resume()


    // use of variable that isn't initialised yet!
    if(self.tableau.count != 0){
    }
}
```

the flow will go as follow:

1. first you create request and fill it with address and body
2. you create downloader and sets it's callback [1]
3. you start downloader [2]
4. [You wait]
5. **background** thread calls your callback [3]

(take note that you can't edit UI elements on background thread)

So your code should be as follow:

```swift
@IBAction func sendButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Send HTTP GET Request

              // Define server side script URL
              let scriptUrl = "https://lora-thomas-slave.data.thethingsnetwork.org/api/v2/query?last=7d"

              // Create NSURL Ibject
              let myUrl = NSURL(string: scriptUrl);

              // Creaste URL Request
               let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);

              // Set request HTTP method to GET. It could be POST as well
               request.httpMethod = "GET"

              // Or it could be a single Authorization Token value
               request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
               request.addValue("key ttn-account-v2.*************", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

              // Excute HTTP Request
               URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {(data, response, error) in
                   do{
                       // Try to assign Json Lora data into an array of Structured data
                       let donne = try JSONDecoder().decode([Donnee].self, from: data!)

                       // For each data, print the received string
                       let compt: Int = donne.count         //compt = number of json objects
                       var j : Int = 0
                       var chaine: String = " "
                       var x : Int = 0
                       for i in donne{
                           if (j > (compt-6)){
                               chaine = i.time.split(separator: "T")[0]  + " " + i.time.split(separator: "T")[1].split(separator: ".")[0] + " : " + i.receivedString
                               self.tableau.append(chaine)
                               x += 1
                           }
                           j += 1
                       }
                       DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                            if(self.tableau.count != 0){
                                self.labelMess0.text = self.tableau[4]
                                self.labelMess1.text = self.tableau[3]
                                self.labelMess2.text = self.tableau[2]
                                self.labelMess3.text = self.tableau[1]
                                self.labelMess4.text = self.tableau[0]
                             }
                       }
                   }catch{
                       print("error !")
                   }
               }.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Yes, i got it :) thanks, the first time i pushed on the button the label change well (with the DispatchQueue.main.async......) but when i push again on the button (with values changed into Table ) the UILabel doesn't seems to update ... :/